# Best way to build twice the same webapp with different dependencies using maven

Tags: java, maven, war

I have a maven project with a webapp for which I need two versions, each one having its own set of dependencies. The intent is to support two different (and conflicting) versions of a storage client. The webapp code, configuration file and anything but certain libraries is the same in both cases. The right client is loaded at runtime : I just need to drop the right jar (and its dependencies) in the lib folder of the webapp.

If I deploy the dependencies manually, I lose the opportunity to check for version conflicts (which I do when I build a maven project with all its dependencies correctly set).

I do not want to deploy the webapp(s) on the maven repository since it is not a library and it only makes a big archive (mainly because of the embedded dependencies) that consumes space for nothing. Thus, to build the final wars, I cannot add a dependency on the webapp project.

I do not want to duplicate the common webapp class files and configuration files in two different modules. It would make future evolutions more difficult because of the necessary synchronization between the two modules each time one file is updated.

Any suggestion on how to solve this ?

Note that the best solution should allow to build both wars at once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end, I did not use profiles. There was an issue building both webapp versions at once.

Instead I used war overlays https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/overlays.html.

First, I created a skinny war version of the webapp. The skinny war does not include libraries nor META-INF files. Only resources like configuration files. The webapp classes are packaged in a jar (using the `attachedClasses` configuration option of the `maven-war-plugin`). I do not mind having this war deployed since it is very lightweigth. Here is the configuration of the `maven-war-plugin` :

```
            <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <outputFileNameMapping>@{groupId}@.@{artifactId}@-@{version}@@{dashClassifier?}@.@{extension}@</outputFileNameMapping>
                <attachClasses>true</attachClasses>
                <archive>
                    <addMavenDescriptor>false</addMavenDescriptor>
                </archive>
                <packagingExcludes>WEB-INF/classes/**/*,WEB-INF/lib/*</packagingExcludes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Then, I created 2 additional modules, one for each flavour of the webapp. In the dependencies, I set :
 - the webapp as a dependency of type war
 - the jar of the webapp classes
 - the storage client library
That way, maven checks for dependency conflicts in all the libraries. The webapp classes are imported through the dependency. The overlay war is used to build the final war. No duplicate code between the 2 flavours of the webapp. Only the client dependency changes between the 2 pom files. Here is an excerpt of one of them :

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.storage</groupId>
        <artifactId>client</artifactId>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.group.id</groupId>
        <artifactId>webapp</artifactId>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
        <classifier>classes</classifier>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.group.id</groupId>
        <artifactId>webapp</artifactId>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
        <type>war</type>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>                   
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <skip>true</skip>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <skip>true</skip>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: Thanks for your feedback ! You should accept your own answer :)

Answer (score 3):

Use Maven profiles.

http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html

You can put certain dependencies into certain profiles and activate/deactivate them through the command line with the `-P` parameter.

Answer (score 3):

I guess defining two profiles in your pom might do the trick :

```
<project [...]>
    [...]
    <profiles>

      <profile>
        <id>storage1</id>
        <dependencies>
          <dependency>
             <groupId>my.group.storage</groupId>
             <artifactId>thisOne</artifactId>
             <version>13</version>
          </dependency>
        </dependencies>
      </profile>

      <profile>
        <id>storage2</id>
        <dependencies>
          <dependency>
             <groupId>my.group.storage</groupId>
             <artifactId>thisOtherOne</artifactId>
             <version>37</version>
          </dependency>
        </dependencies>
      </profile>

    </profiles>
    [...]
</project>
```

Call one or the other with `mvn -P storage1` or `mvn -P storage2`. You can also make one active by default, use activation triggers based on other properties, etc.

[Here](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html)'s their introduction article.

Comment: Right : I had missed dependency management in profiles :-/ I am almost done, I still have to automate the execution of both profiles.